# Get view from another, not parent, view

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to link together 2 views. ViewPager and view which indicates this ViewPager state, something like tabs, but it can be displayed differently (same as usual tabs, one text view, but just text will changed), its just implements some interface. 
Programaticaly i can do this, something like

```
myViewPager.setIndicator(myIndicatorView);
```

But, for this i must, in some parent view, find this 2 views and call this method. I want to simplify it, and have an ability to manage it simply in xml schema.
Here example of xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.example.views.TextTabs
        android:id="@+id/info_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/info_tabs_height"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient" />

    <com.example.views.InfoPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        custom:tabs="@id/info_tabs" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm created custom attribute and put in it reference to id of view. So my constructor is:

```
public ViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //Getting view id from xml attribute
    TypedArray attr = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ViewPager);

    //This id equals R.id.info_tabs
    int id = attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.ViewPager_tabs, -1);
    if (id != -1) {
        //i want to find view from all activity
        View tabs = ((Activity) context).findViewById(id);
        if (tabs != null && tabs instanceof ViewPagerTabs) {
            // if tabs finded
            mTabs = (ViewPagerTabs) tabs;
            setIndicator(mTabs);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that i can't get view by id. The idea is that indicator view can be in different places, it can be sibling to pager, it can be in higher level to pager and so on. This is why i'm trying to find it from Activity. But i can't find it even from parent view, because getParent return null.

So how can i find view from another view which is not his parent? Or maybe you have any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that the view is not attached, so i added onAttachChangeListener to this view and when it is attached i'm searching for view again.

```
//This id equals R.id.info_tabs
int id = attr.getResourceId(R.styleable.ViewPager_tabs, -1);
if (id != -1) {
    //i want to find view from all activity
    View tabs = ((Activity) context).findViewById(id);
    if (tabs != null && tabs instanceof ViewPagerTabs) {
        // if tabs finded
        mTabs = (ViewPagerTabs) tabs;
        setIndicator(mTabs);
    } else {

        //If we didn't find view - add listener, and waiting while this view will attached
        addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener {
            @Override
            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
                View tabs = ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(mTabsViewId);
                //
                if (tabs != null && tabs instanceof ViewPagerTabs) {
                        setIndicator((ViewPagerTabs) tabs);
                }
                //Remove this listener it's not usefull anymore
                removeOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good, but calling `addOnAttachStateChangeListener(null);` dosn't actually remove the listener and might even cause a null pointer exception because you're telling it to call `null.onViewAttachedToWindow` next time it gets attached, I'd use `removeOnAttachStateChangeListener` if you want to do that.